# Unwanted white space with knitr+booktabs package

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I want to include a table in my latex document that I create using knitr package. I "call" the table using:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{centering}
<<r second part}>>=
kable(Per_cond, booktabs=T,row.names=F)
@
\par\end{centering}
\begin{centering}
\protect\caption{Summary of plate}
\par\end{centering}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
```

The results is amazing as usual, but as you can see below, some white space is added after every 5 rows.

[image]

When created with `booktabs=F` those white spaces disappear (second image).

[image]

Do you know a way to get rid of those white spaces or (even better) to select where they appear (in this case if they would come after every 4 rows, they would nicely separate my conditions) ? Thank you for your help.

(RStudio 0.98.1062, knitr v 1.9, MikTex 2.9, booktabs packaged 2005-05-04)

Comment: Don't use the `centering` environment. Instead just call `\centering`.

Comment: I changed my code, works nicely, but if I may ask, what's the difference ?

Comment: `\centering` is a declaration, even though you can use it as an environment. If you do, it provides a limit scope, and this seems to defeat the purpose in your case, since you're using it twice within the same environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the source of `kable`, it calls `knitr:::kable_latex` if you're using LaTeX. Then, looking at that source, it has the following argument and default:

```
linesep = if (booktabs) c("", "", "", "", "\\addlinespace")
```

So, I'm guessing if you explicitly pass

```
linesep = c("", "", "", "\\addlinespace")
```

you'll get spaces every 4 lines as desired.